# Jquery + binding an event to an element with negative z-index

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed DIV (footer banner) with several DIV's within it.

[image]

On the right hand side there is a HIDE DIV (part of the footer banner) and when clicked it hides the other parts of the DIV and sets the overall z-index (of footer banner) to -1 so the website underneath this banner is clickable/accessible.

Once Hide is clicked it looks like this - just hide DIV remains on the right (this will be renamed to 'show' later once minimized like this:

[image]

I'm doing it like this so the width of this DIV is maintained - it will re-size if user zooms in/out of the page and depending on the users screen size.

The issue I have is I want to be able to click on this remaining Hide DIV, capture a click event and re-show all aspects of this fixed footer DIV, however because of the z-index -1 on the parent I can't capture the click event.

I tried mousein/mouseout and this doesn't work.

I tried increases the z-index on this remaining hide DIV but that doesn't seem to overwrite the fact that its parent DIV has a negative z-index.

Is there a way I can capture a click event on this DIV?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the parent's z-index to -1, select those exact divs to hide with jQuery and call hide/show when button is clicked: `$('.divs').hide()` and to reappear: `$('.divs').show()`.